# How to download only packages suitable for 64 bit architecture?

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I'm using CentOS 7 64bit. I'm trying to download multiple packages with their dependencies using `yumdownloader`. However I'm facing the problem that packages that I do not need are getting downloaded.

When I'm installing  a package using `yum install <package>` only one package is getting installed: either `x86_x64` (if available), or `i686` (if 64bit is not available) or `noarch`. I'm trying to mimic the same behavior to download only the best matching packages with `yumdownloader`. However this does not work as expected and both `x86_x64` and `i686` are getting downloaded for packages that have 2 architectures available. Adding `--archlist=x86_64` does not make any difference. Setting `multilib_policy=best` in a config file does not make any difference either.

I also checked `repoquery` tool. If I set `--archlist=x86_64` then only `x86_64` packags would be listed. Those that have only `i686` or `noarch` versions will not be picked up. If I set `--archlist=x86_64,i686,noarch` then the result is similar to `yumdownloader`, i.e. multiple architectures are being picked up.

Is there a way to list or download only best matching package?

The only option I see is to do it completely manually - prepare lists using `repoquery` and remove duplicates. But I would prefer to find more neat and robust approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do, is use the standard `yum` option for excluding packages. It is "inherited" by `yumdownloader`.

Example:

```
yumdownloader libX11 --archlist=x86_64 --exclude="*.i686"
```

Note that i686 is sort of "subset" to x86_64 due to multilib, and especially applies to libraries (nearly all have i686 equivalent). Make sure you won't have any software that actually requires i686 libraries later on...  The only notable example of such i686-only software I've seen is steam.i686 (there is simply no x86_64 version), but then again who plays that on RHEL? (aside from myself).

Comment: You're right. Due to some mistake when listing packages I had the impression there are many i686-only packages to be installed. Therefore I did not consider this solution But in fact there are no such packages at all and this approach works perfectly fine.